# Returning the documents that were upserted from a BulkWrite operation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to return the documents that were upserted from a bulkwrite operation but it doesn't work. So here is the code in JS:

```js
import Product from '../models/product.model';
import { values } from 'lodash';
let results = []; // this is an array of records to be upserted into the DB, it is not empty
let result = {}
Product.bulkWrite(
            results.map((aproduct) => 
              ({
                updateOne: {
                  filter: {id : aproduct.id},
                  update: {$set: aproduct},
                  upsert: true
                }
              })
            )
          ).then(results => {
             // Trying to fetch the documents that have been upserted by the BulkWrite operation
             Product.find({'_id': { $in: values(results.upsertedIds)}}).then(function(docs) {
                console.info("UPSERTED DOCS: ", docs);
                result.upsertedDocuments = docs;
                console.info("Merged Results: ", result);
                arrNewIds = docs;
              });
          }
      }

// The issue is that from this line, the result object is empty despite being populated in the then as shown above.
// The expected result would have been
// result.upsertedDocuments to hold the upserted documents but it doesn't seem to be case despite the very same variable being populated in the then function
```

Comment: Please discripe what exact Issue you are facing. Are you reciving Errors or does the code not provide the expected output?

Comment: Hi, I am not receiving any errors but just that I can't get the upserted  rows